# Custom post type URL - filter by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Created CPT = news

uses default categories (IT and recruitment)
I am struggling to view an archive of the posts based on their category

mysite/news/ - shows all posts for that CPT whatever the category - good

mysite/news/recruitment - 404

mysite/category/recruitment - 404

mysite/news/category/recruitment - 404

(not sure which one of the last 3 should work)

Here is the code I am using - I imagine I'm missing the basics somewhere - thanks

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );
   function cptui_register_my_cpts() {
   $labels = array(
     "name" => "News",
     "singular_name" => "News",
   );

$args = array(
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "news", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,

    "taxonomies" => array( "category" )
);
register_post_type( "news", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you did pretty url on your site already (Settings>Permalinks). If so, Let's guess your **Category base** is blank there.

You have to add Custom posts in category archive using a filter. To do so, add this to function.php:

```
function go_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'your-custom-post-type-here'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'go_add_custom_types' );
```

In default setup, WordPress Structure act like this (Based on observation on my blog)

For Default category,

site.com/category/catgory-name

or site.com/category-name

For custom taxonomy (by chance)

site.com/custom-taxonomy-slug/category-name

For single news (CPT)

site.com/news/post-name.

For single Default post:

```
site.com/<depends-on-permalink-structure>
```